# Deprecated: mysql_connect() message and Warnings occur in step 3 of the opencart configuration setup after we enter the details and hit continue

Tags: installation, content-management-system, opencart, deprecation-warning

We need help trying to upload our opencart templatemonster.com template correctly  on godaddy but we are not clear on how to do that.

**FYI** our `public_html/system/database` folder contains a mysqli.php file as well.

1. We made sure to upload the template via fullpackage (The name of the file is themeXXX(full).zip, where XXX is your theme number) to the public_html folder.
2. Extracted the zip files in the public_html folder.
3. Performed the installation using the installation manager .
4. At step 3 configuration we were prompted to input our database access details and made sure the database was empty. (GoDaddy told us to use the localhost)

**After hitting continue:**

The deprecated: `mysql_connect()` message and Warnings occur in step 3 of the opencart configuration setup after we enter the details and hit continue.

> Where ‘store’ is the new directory name. Where ‘user’ is your server
>   account address. Where ‘yourdomainname.co.uk’ is the web domain of
>   your new website:

(DUMMY LINK FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES) http://www.yourdomainname.co.uk/install/index.php?route=step_3

> **Deprecated**: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in **/home/user /public_html/system/database/mysql.php** on line **6**

**Lines 5-16**:

```
public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database) {
    if (!$this->link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)) {
        trigger_error('Error: Could not make a database link using ' . $username . '@' . $hostname);
    }

    if (!mysql_select_db($database, $this->link)) {
        trigger_error('Error: Could not connect to database ' . $database);
    }
```

Errors:

> **Warning**: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at `/home/user/public_html/system/database/mysql.php`:6) in `/home/user/public_html/system/engine/controller.php` on line **28**
>
> **Warning**: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at `/home/user/public_html/system/database/mysql.php`:6) in `/home/user/public_html/system/engine/controller.php` on line **29**

**Lines 27-31**

```
protected function redirect($url, $status = 302) {
    header('Status: ' . $status);
    header('Location: ' . str_replace(array('&amp;', "\n", "\r"), array('&', '', ''), $url));
    exit();             
}
```

---

### **Template Features**

- OpenCart Compatibility:  1.5.6.x
- OpenCart Engine: 1.5.6.4

  (Trimmed)

### **Sources Available**

PSD PNG PHP TPL JS

### **Hosting Requirements**

- Web Server (preferably Apache)
- PHP (at least 5.2)
- MySQL
- Curl
- Fsock

[OpenCart Templates Help Center](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/quick-start-guide/opencart-templates/master/index_en.html)

### **Software Required**

- Adobe Photoshop CS+
- For uncompressing a template ZIP package: WinZip 9+ (Windows);
  Stuffit Expander 10+ (Mac)
- Apache Server
- PHP v. 5 or higher
- MySQL 4.1.14 or later
- OpenCart 1.5.6.4
- Sublime Text2 or later, Notepad++ or any php-editor

A commenter stated

> `mysql_ calls` will work on this server but are causing deprecation
>   notices. A quick fix would be to turn off warnings in your `php.ini`
>   file, in your `error_reporting` value. Or you could try turning off
>   display errors, set `display_errors to 0`.

I like the comment but could someone provide a slightly more comprehensive explanation or visual resource to this suggestion? Such as articulating a little further how to proceed? Should I download the file through GoDaddys public FTP or should I use FileZilla FTP client (does it matter), make a copy, make the proper changes then re-upload?

I like the possible solution but I am curious to know if these are the only ones.

### **UPDATE**

- I just changed display_errors = 1; to display_errors = 0;
- saved the file (I edited the file withing GoDaddy's text editor)
- re-input our database access details
- hit continue on step 3 configuration and got the same error.

### php.ini

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
register_globals = Off;
default_charset = UTF-8;
memory_limit = 64M;
max_execution_time = 36000;
upload_max_filesize = 999M;
safe_mode = Off;
mysql.connect_timeout = 20;
session.use_only_cookies = On;
session.use_trans_sid = Off;
session.cookie_httponly = On;
session.gc_maxlifetime = 172800;
allow_url_fopen = on;
;display_errors = 0;
;error_reporting = E_ALL;
```

???

Comment: No but thank you sir and question edited.

Comment: Your `mysql_` calls will work on this server but are causing deprecation notices. A quick fix would be to turn off warnings in your `php.ini` file, in your `error_reporting` value. Or you could try turning off display errors, set `display_errors` to `0`.

Comment: I would be surprised if OpenCart did not support PDO though - have you got `PDO` and `pdo_mysql` extensions loaded? If you can get OpenCart to use PDO instead, then the deprecation notices should stop.

Comment: Well, I have offered two possible solutions - please do try them! (Questions that are on hold are still public, but they may not feature on the front page for as long as an open upvoted question, if I recall correctly).

Comment: What and how do you load the PDO and pdo_mysql extensions.

Comment: (On a live server you do not want errors to be displayed anyway, as it is a security risk. There is therefore no downside to resetting `display_errors` - if you need to do development work on a site you should be using a copy).

Comment: To enable these extensions, try [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=enable+pdo+mysql+php.ini) - always do a search!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120908/discussion-between-robert-dove-and-halfer).

Comment: Do you have access to your `php.ini` file on this hosting plan? If so, open it and find your `display_errors` entry. Reset it to `0`, and restart Apache if necessary (if you do not know how to restart Apache it may not be necessary on this plan).

Comment: @halfer I just changed display_errors = 1; to display_errors = 0; > saved the file (I edited the file withing GoDaddy's text editor) > re-input our database access details > hit continue on step 3 configuration and got the same error.

Comment: Try creating a temporary PHP file in your filing system thus: `<?php echo ini_get('display_errors'); ?>`. View it in your browser - if the ini setting has worked, it should show nothing.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for posting your `php.ini` file. Your `;display_errors = 0;` is commented out - remove the semi-colon prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar experience! You don't need to enable these extensions the PHP Version needs to be update:

1. Sign into GoDaddy
2. Go to My Products under your sign in name at the top right.
3. Go to Web Hosting and click the Manage button.
4. Click manage again.
5. Scroll to the Software header and click "Select PHP Version"
6. Then change to an earlier version, in which this extension is not deprecated.

Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: Perfect so all I needed to do was change the php version. Wow!

Comment: Ah, @RobertDove - this works because you've used an old version of PHP where the MySQL extension is not deprecated. It's not a long term fix - you should be keeping up to date with the latest supported versions of PHP.

Comment: @halfer how would I update my opencart template to be compatible with the latest supported versions of PHP it was on 5.6 and I changed it to 5.4. I know its not a long term fix though but I would not know how to fix it for good? Where would I start?

Comment: See my previous answers, @RobertDove. It is somewhat better to be on 5.6 and turn off the on-screen deprecation notices. It is even better to swap to PDO/MySQL (or MySQLi). The latter depends on whether your system supports PDO or MySQLi; OpenCart is certainly likely to, but you'd need to check whether the template does. Have a look at the code, or ask the author.

Comment: It may be worth you getting a support person for this - running an online store safely does require some technical expertise, unless you can pass it over to an all-in-one host such as Shopify. There may be one available for OpenCart, and if this site produces more than a residual income, it may be worth protecting that by getting the right support contracts in place.